# Windows on secondary monitor appear in every workspace in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, gnome3

I am running GNOME 3.30.2 in Debian 10.6 with a dual monitor setup, and have some trouble with the workspaces. If I open a window in the area corresponding to my primary display on e.g. workspace 1, then this window appears only in workspace 1. However, if I place the window in the area corresponding to my secondary display, then that window appears on *all* four workspaces. Is this intended behaviour? Is there anyway I can change it so that a window, whether in the area corresponding to the primary or the secondary display, appears in one workspace, and one workspace only?

Answer (score 1):

The author of the question found the following solution:

> I found a solution in Karl Wilbur's answer over here: [Switching workspaces on primary display only](https://askubuntu.com/q/837813/1112981). One can change these settings using the tool `gnome-tweaks`.

The relevant part from [Karl Wilbur's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183794/1112981) tells:

> ### Config
>
> - select Workspaces from the left-hand list (at the bottom)
> - under "Display Handling", select
>
>   - "Workspaces on primary display only" (for all other displays as "static")
>   - "Workspaces span displays" (for all displays as a single, shared workspace)
>
> Ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1767564/comments/6